# I try to print in TensorBoard an audio with tf.summary.audio any audio is shown

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, tensorboard

I'm using Python 3.6 and TensorFlow 1.8 in a Linux environment. I'm trying to print an audio in TensorBoard with the following code, and even is storing a file, no audio is printed.

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('graphs', sess.graph)
    audio = tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 4 * 10 * 2), (4, 10, 2))
    tf.summary.audio('k488', audio, 2)
    writer.close()
```

I have been looking examples or information, but there is no much about tf.summary.audio. This is a example that I found but can't make it work.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

audio = tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 4 * 10 * 2), (4, 10, 2))
audio_summary = tf.summary.audio('k488', audio, 2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('graphs', sess.graph)
    audio_summary_value = sess.run(audio_summary)
    writer.add_summary(summary=audio_summary_value)
    writer.close()
```

Hopefully that works (I don't have anything to test with) but basically the issue I see with your code is that you're not teling the writer to explicitly write the summary